# javascript set variable conditional in initialize

Tags: javascript

Simple question, but i'm stucked...

I want to set the plusmin on initialisation dependant on the defaultQty.

So is the defaultQty = 1 (of an other whole number like 2 or 3) then the plusmin has to be 1.

If it's not a whole integer (like 0.5) the plusmin has to be 0.1

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function (ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            //initialize parent Component
            this._super();
            this.qty = ko.observable(this.defaultQty);
            this.plusmin = 0.1;
        },

        decreaseQty: function() {
            var newQty = this.qty() - this.plusmin;
            if (newQty < this.defaultQty) {
                newQty = this.defaultQty;
            }
            this.qty(newQty);
        },

        increaseQty: function() {
            var newQty = this.qty() + this.plusmin;
            this.qty(newQty);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: this.plusmin = ( this.qty == Math.floor(this.qty) ) ? 1 : 0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.plusmin = (this.defaultQty % 1 === 0) ? 1 : 0.1;`

Comment: Yep! This is it! in 4 minutes i can accept the answer. But when i go to 0.8 in some way 0,7999999999999999 appears in the input field. Is there a way to (conditional) round the number to 0,8 when it is not a whole number?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you need here.  JavaScript gets funny with number precision in ways such as the above, but it shouldn't affect the answer to this question.  If that's an entirely new issue, then just ask it as a new question.

Comment: Used var newQty = Math.round((this.qty() - this.plusmin) * 100) / 100; to do the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *modulus* operator (`%`) which returns the remainder after dividing:

```
(defaultQty % 1) > 0 ? plusmin = 0.1 : plusmin = 1;
```